# I'm having a GRFINGER.DLL missing error -996 on VFP

Tags: visual-foxpro

The company that I am working at is still using visual foxpro, and I am doing a fingerprint scanner using vfp9 and Griaule Fingerprint SDK 2009.

Everything is doing fine during the first run of the program. But when I re-run it againg. The error will happen. Any ideas why I keep on having that problem? Missing GRFINGER.DLL.

It's getting hard for me to find any support today because foxpro application development is getting obsolete.

Comment: When you talk about re-running the program, do you mean that you shut down the application and start it again, or that you make the same menu selection again?

Comment: i mean i stop the program, but I am not exiting in foxpro. Then when I run the program again, the error exists. But when I exit the foxpro and open my program again. It will run smoothly on the first. and on the second on so on, it won't run anymore because of the error. So the plot is: Without exiting the foxpro, my program will only run once. I need to re open it again to run it properly.

Comment: Can you share some of the source code?  Specifically, the code in and around where the error is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

The rub of the problem seems to be that the first run causes Fox to be somehow unable to find the DLL or to load it. The latter can occur if the DLL itself is findable but one of its dependencies (like its C runtime DLL) is not.

This may be due to a changed search path (`SET PATH`). If the search path contains relative directories then a simple change of the current working directory changes the *effective* search path, even though the actual text (`set("PATH")`) remains unchanged. That can happen because of things like file open/save dialogues, for example.

P.S.: sorry for the belated answer - the question was at the top of the recent/active list because someone had edited the question recently, and only after posting the answer did I realise how old the question was. However, the answer might still be useful for someone with a similar problem.